# Get path relative to project directory from within Typescript module compiled to JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, path

I have a directory structure like

```
- project
|- build
|- src
 |- index.ts
 |- file.txt
```

The typescript is compiled to the `build` directory and executed from there. I'm looking for a reliable way to access `file.txt` from the compiled module without having to account for the location of the build output.

For example, I could just assume that the file is at `../src/file.txt` relative to the `index.js` in `build` but if the build output changes, that needs to be changed as well.

Is there possibly a way to pass root directory into an environment variable before the typescript is compiled?

Comment: Why is your txt file in `src` anyways?

Comment: Is this a terminal application or a web app, or something else?

Comment: Like the answers before why `file.txt` is not at the root folder like that you could call it from your build directly by passing `/file.txt` example

Comment: `file.txt` doesn't have to be in `src` it can be in the project directory. Trying to call `/file.txt` will only get me to the drive root.

Comment: An example would be data to build a model or run tests against

Answer (score 0):

If you using webpack, you can insert a resolve, see documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

and a example:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
      Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/'),
    },
  },
};
```

You can too use vscode jsconfig.json you can use compilerOptions, see documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

example:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "@background/*": ["src/background/*"],
      "@frontend/*": ["src/frontend/*"],
      "@mixins/*": ["src/frontend/mixins/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice attempt at an answer! But I'll say nobody uses webpack for typescript these days, unless they're using some other bundler which wraps webpack, but even those aren't used in server-side code. The second answer is more relevant, but it uses a jsConfig, when you can use the tsconfig anyway, because OP is using TS. But also, the paths only work for imports, not reading files (if I'm not mistaken)